# verifying receipts against the sandbox URL in a production app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, in-app-purchase

by mistake I forget to change the sandbox validation url to the production one and unfortunately the app is live now? my question is what will happen if someone purchase from the app! is the purchase will success or fail??

Please advice ASAP.

Comment: maybe try making a purchase from the live app yourself?

Comment: The validation will fail. Quickly resubmit with the update.